# Algorithm for evaluating polynomials

Tags: time-complexity, algorithm-analysis

I'm reading *The Algorithm Design Manual* and I stumbled upon this problem.
I can't really get my head around this, I don't even know how the number of multiplications could differ, what I mean is that there is no polynomial that would make this algorithm perform poorly.
I also have no idea how this could get improved, every operation seems necessary to me.

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: picture of the question]

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method

Comment: Thanks a lot, got my answer. :)

Comment: Why don't you write up an answer?

Comment: I didn't know. I'll do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of multiplications in the algorithm is $2n - 1$, but the number of multiplications in the Horner's method is $n$, which means this algorithm is not optimal.

As mentioned in the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) page, Horner's method in evaluating a polynomial is optimal, therefore we can change this algorithm so that it uses the Horner's method.

```
p = a[n]

for i = n-1 to 0:
   p = p.x + a[i]
```